# ipython notebook is NOT printing until the whole program is finished

Tags: python, printing, jupyter-notebook, progress

```
import time

print 1
time.sleep(5)
```

I ran the code above in IPython notebook and normal script separately.

In `IPython Notebook`, it doesn't print the number '1' until `time.sleep(5)` is finished, while in normal script it DOES print out number '1' first and go into `time.sleep(5)`. What would that happen?

This example is just to illustrate my problem: I use `print` to print out some text at every stage in my code, which takes a long time to finish, so that I can know where the programme has got to. I found this works fine when executing the script, but in `IPython Notebook` `print` often lags behind and everything is printed out when the whole program is finished.

Is there any way to solve this in `IPython Notebook`?

Comment: the notebook must wait for the code to finish before you see the output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: you don't need to wait for the script to finish before you can see the output. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26352157/4279)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a buffering issue. Add `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print, to see the output immediately. You could also use `python -u` command or set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` envvar. See [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/4279).

python uses line-buffering if it is run interactively (in a terminal) and block buffering (e.g., ~4K bytes buffers) if the output is redirected. Compare:

```
$ python your_script.py
```

And

```
$ python your_script.py | cat
```

The output is delayed in the second case.

See the second reason in [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

Comment: I was having the problem with displaying output from python script gitlab deployment task and adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print command solved my issue. Now the output prints out as the script executes.